# Getting height of table rows using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, html-table

So I have a table like so: [image: This Table]

That has a dynamic amount of rows based on the size of its container, and the size of each row.

If you look at the link column, each row is capable of having multiple links like this.

[image: 2nd Table]

If you notice, the pagination at the bottom got thrown off. That's because currently when I do the reflowing or resizing of the table I was given the info that each row would have one link. That changed and each row now has multiple links. Here is how the reflowing worked before:

```
 var el = $element.closest('.gridster-item'); 
 var height = el.height();                    
 vm.dsHeight = 36;                            
 vm.pageHeight = 52;                          
 var calcHeight = vm.dsHeight + vm.pageHeight;
 var rowHeight = height - calcHeight - 40;    
 var rows = Math.floor(rowHeight / 27) - 1;   


 vm.numPerPage = rows < 0 ? 5 : rows;
```

Where you see the var rows = Math.floor(rowHeight/27) - 1, the 27 was the previously assumed constant row height.

Now the rows with multiple links either have a height of 27 pixels, or a height of 27 + 16(n-1), for n >= 1 links, and 27 + 16n for n = 0 links.

I'm trying to find the best way to work with the function to get an appropriate value of rows based on the pixel heights. My first thought was take the average of all the heights, but I'm having an issue accessing that piece of DOM with Angular. Here's how the HTML looks for it.

```
<tbody>

    <tr align="left" ng-repeat="row in tableRows track by $index">
        <td nowrap ng-repeat="col in row.data track by $index"><span ng-bind-html="col"></span></td>

    </tr>

    </tbody>
```

For some reason I can access the outer tbody element when I do an $element.find('tbody'), but when I try to go to the children of it or access height I get null or undefined. I don't know how to access the height otherwise, and can't think of other good ways to change the amount of rows based on a varying row pixel height.

Comment: Where does this code run? Is it in an Angular directive?

Comment: It's in a controller.

Comment: We cannot help without all of the code. You can create a JSFiddle or like.

Comment: The problem is probably that the code is executed before that the table is fully rendered and you need the rendered table in order to calculate the height from the DOM elements. If you could find a way to calculate it from the data before rendering, it would make more sense that way.

Comment: I can figure out a way to do it before rendering. That helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks each link is on a reparate row. Is it correct? If so, can't you just count the number of 
 elements or  elements and get the number of rows from this count?

Comment: sorry, the br and a element names got lost.

Comment: I think I have an idea of what to do. So I have the HTML strings stored in a variable in my controller as the Angular app processes them. So what I can do is go through the table rows array it's in, access the data array within each table row and access the link cell, and then do a check for the amount of links in each string (probably a search for the amount of times href is seen), and then do the rows based on that.